# Can constructor return a null object?

Tags: java, constructor, null

While looking through some old code I came across this gem:

```
MyObject o = new MyObject("parameter");
if (o == null) o = new MyObject("fallback parameter");
```

The second line is marked in Eclipse as dead code, and I understand why. No exception seems to be explicitly thrown, and it isn't possible for the `MyObject` constructor to throw any kind of exception (such as `NullPointerException`s).

My question is *why* there is a null check? Was it previously possible in an old version of Java for a constructor to return null? Or is this simply useless and dead code?

Comment: Not relevant. The question is very simple: can a constructor return null? You don't need to know what it is used for.

Comment: The OP asked "why this is there". Do you have an answer for that question?

Comment: @AlexLockwood The answer, as everyone below gently put it, is that this is there for no real reason, as what it does is completely useless. There is no reason since o can never be null, and that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: Oh... well since you asked "why this is there?", I assumed that it wasn't your code. That's why I asked "what is this code for..."

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The code is dead in any version of Java. It's not possible for a constructor to return `null`, and even if an exception would be thrown from the constructor, the next line won't be called.

Comment: Incorrect. It's very possible for a constructor to return a Null. 
Try running the following code and see what you get:
android.net.wifi.WifiEnterpriseConfig conf = new android.net.wifi.WifiEnterpriseConfig();

Also, see the response from @PhantomLord below in the thread

Comment: @OkeUwechue PhantomLord's example returns null from a static factory method, not from a constructor. I also cannot reproduce what you're saying with your example, please add more context to it.

Answer (score 55):

No, it has never been possible. Maybe a previous version of the code used some factory method which could return null:

```
MyObject o = createMyObject("parameter");
if (o == null) o = createMyObject("fallback parameter");
```

Answer (score 53):

From [section 15.9.4 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.4):

> The value of a class instance creation expression is a reference to the newly created object of the specified class. Every time the expression is evaluated, a fresh object is created.

So no, it can never return null.

Comment: Thanks. I know it sounds crazy.. but in my code, a constructor somehow returns null. (Java, Android)

Comment: @AhamadAnees: That sounds very unlikely to me. If you still think it's the case, I suggest you post a [mcve] as a new question.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responds. But unfortunately I can't post new questions here.

Comment: @AhamadAnees: Well adding comments instead isn't going to help. As I say, I think it's far more likely that you've misdiagnosed what's going on than that Java on Android is *actually* behaving that way... but maybe you need to ask on an Android help forum instead if you can't ask here. (Or maybe you should improve your old questions so that you *can* post new questions here...)

Answer (score 30):

My guess is that it was written by a C programmer who is used to testing the return value of `malloc()` for `NULL`,  `malloc()` can return `NULL` if your system runs out of memory.

The code doesn't make sense in Java since Java will throw an OutOfMemoryError` if it runs out of memory.

Comment: Actually it's an [`OutOfMemoryError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) ;-)

Comment: @JoachimSauer Oops. Good catch.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 11):

As I discovered today, despite what's said in all the other answers, `Foo x = new Foo(...)` can indeed return null, if said code is running inside a test that uses [PowerMock](https://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#whenNew%28java.lang.Class%29) (or some other mocking framework with similar effects):

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(Foo.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockFoo);
```

In this case, the code in the constructor(s) of Foo is bypassed altogether for `new Foo(...)`. But if you write a test where you fail to specify the mock in the manner above, you may end up with `null` instead.

But *even if* you are using such a framework, you don't want extra code in your classes, just to gracefully handle the case that you forgot to properly mock the objects in a test! It is *not* a real-world scenario where your code is intended to run. Code that is only ever active when testing should be eliminated anyway, and in this case it would only ever be active for a broken test.

So even if you're using PowerMock, that second line should rightly be considered "dead code" and removed.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is simple: person who wrote the code was a paranoid c++ programmer. In C++  you may overload operator new and use it as a simple memory allocator (aka malloc).

Answer (score 4):

This was simply usesless dead code. Once CTOR has executed successfully, you have reference to the object.

Answer (score 4):

When you create a *new Object()*, you create an address in memory, and this address is not 'null', but your Object may be empty.

You have to test 'null' for Object transmitted by parameters.

Answer (score 4):

It's simply dead code.

`new MyObject("parameter")` will not return `null` in any version of java.

Answer (score 1):

The question is absolutely legitimate. You can add a static method in `MyObject` like so:

```
static MyObject create(String parameter)) {
       if (parameter.satisfySomething())
          return new MyObject(parameter);
       else
          return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All the answers are based on theoretical and editor's warnings.

Indeed most editors will report a dead code when testing the results of a new object() against null.

However, at least on Android, I have many crash reports of a new xxx() returning null, and I assume because of lack of memory in most cases.

A simple example is like so:

```
object_class obj = new object_class(context);
obj.getCount();
```

And I get such report on the getCount() line:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int object_class.getCount()' on a null object reference

So it's possible, but most editors/compilers won't let you check for such condition.

Comment: BTW, spelling standard for classes is (upper) camel case, that is, it should be `ObjectClass`, not `object_class` in Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;

public class GroupButtonSelection {
    public int index = -1;
    public AbstractButton button = null;

    public static GroupButtonSelection from(ButtonGroup buttonGroup) {
        GroupButtonSelection result = new GroupButtonSelection();

        Enumeration<AbstractButton> buttons = buttonGroup.getElements();
        for (int i = 0; buttons.hasMoreElements(); i++) {
            AbstractButton button = buttons.nextElement();
            if (button.isSelected()) {
                result.index = i;
                result.button = button;
                break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Using:

```
Boolean isMyValueSelected = GroupButtonSelection.from(myGroup).index == searchingIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

A constructor should never return `null`, when being called with valid arguments. If your constructor isn’t able to create an instance of that class as one would expect it, it should throw an appropiate `Exception`. The calling code should handle that exception.

```
MyObject myObjectInstance;
try {
    myObjectInstance = new MyObject(params);
} catch (ExpectableException e) {
    myObjectInstance = null;
}
```