# NullException when trying to start an activity

Tags: java, android

I want my object to hit a wall. When my sprites collide I want to launch a new screen saying "You crashed".

I keep getting the same error though!

```
    package com.example.rushhour;

    import java.util.Random;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;


public class TrafficSprite extends PlayScreen {
       Random rand = new Random();
       private int x = 5;
       private int y = 30;
       private int xSpeed = 0;
       private int ySpeed = 0;
       private GameView gameView;
       private PlayScreen playScreen;
       private Sprite sprite;
       private Bitmap bmp;
       private int width;
       private int height;
       private MediaPlayer crashsound;



       public TrafficSprite(GameView gameView, Bitmap bmp) {
             this.gameView = gameView;
             this.playScreen = playScreen;
             this.sprite = sprite;
             this.bmp = bmp;
             this.width = bmp.getWidth();
             this.height = bmp.getHeight();
             System.out.println(gameView.getWidth());
             int randomwidth = gameView.getWidth();
             Math.abs(randomwidth);
             x=rand.nextInt(760);
       }



       private void update(){
        collision();   
        ySpeed = 10;
        y+=ySpeed;



       }

       **private void collision(){
           Rect policerect = new Rect(Sprite.getPolicex(),Sprite.getPolicey(),Sprite.getPolicex()+Sprite.getPoliceWidth(),Sprite.getPolicey()+Sprite.getPoliceHeight());
           Rect trafficsprite = new Rect(x,y,x+bmp.getWidth(),y+bmp.getHeight());
           if (Rect.intersects(policerect, trafficsprite)){
               GameView.getCrashSound().start();
               CrashScreen();

           }

       }

       public void CrashScreen(){
        System.out.println("hi");
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, Crash.class);
          startActivity(intent);

    }**



       public void drawTraffic(Canvas canvas) {

                 update();
                 Rect src = new Rect (0,0,width,height);
                 Rect dst = new Rect (x,y,x+width,y+height);
                 canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, src, dst, null);

}

}
```

This is where I create the intent:

```
public void CrashScreen(){
            System.out.println("hi");
              Intent intent = new Intent(this, Crash.class);
              startActivity(intent);
```

This is the error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6714
12-03 17:57:46.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6013): Process: com.example.rushhour, PID: 6013
12-03 17:57:46.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6013): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
12-03 17:57:46.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6013):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:131)
12-03 17:57:46.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6013):     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
12-03 17:57:46.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6013):     at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3996)
12-03 17:57:46.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6013):     at com.example.rushhour.TrafficSprite.CrashScreen(TrafficSprite.java:65)
12-03 17:57:46.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6013):     at com.example.rushhour.TrafficSprite.collision(TrafficSprite.java:58)
12-03 17:57:46.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6013):     at com.example.rushhour.TrafficSprite.update(TrafficSprite.java:45)
12-03 17:57:46.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6013):     at com.example.rushhour.TrafficSprite.drawTraffic(TrafficSprite.java:82)
12-03 17:57:46.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6013):     at com.example.rushhour.GameView.createTraffic(GameView.java:218)
12-03 17:57:46.497: E/AndroidRuntime(6013):     at com.example.rushhour.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:25)
```

Play Screen is the Activity, it has a "gameView"on top

```
setContentView(new GameView(this));
```

Gameview:

```
package com.example.rushhour;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;



public class GameView extends SurfaceView {
       private Bitmap background,police,audi;
       private Sprite policesprite;
       private TrafficSprite audisprite;

       private List<TrafficSprite> trafficsprites = new ArrayList<TrafficSprite>();
       private SurfaceHolder holder;
       private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
       private int x = 0;
       final Handler handler = new Handler();
       private int i =-1;
       public static MediaPlayer crashsound;


       public GameView(Context context) {
             super(context);
             gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
             holder = getHolder();
             crashsound = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.crash);
             holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

                    @Override
                    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                        boolean retry = true;
                        gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);
                        while (retry){
                               try {
                                     gameLoopThread.join();
                                     retry = false;
                               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                               }
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                        createSprites();
                        gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                        gameLoopThread.start();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                                  int width, int height) {
                    }
             });

             background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.playbackground);
             police = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.policered);
             audi = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.audi);
             policesprite = new Sprite(this,police);
             audisprite = new TrafficSprite(this,audi);




       }

       private void createSprites() {
           final int[] spriteID = { 
                   R.drawable.amb,
                   R.drawable.audi,
                   R.drawable.car,
                   R.drawable.mini,
                   R.drawable.truck,
                   R.drawable.taxi,
                   R.drawable.van
                   // etc for as many images you have
           };
           new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                        if (i == 5){
                            mediumspeed();
                        }
                        Random generator = new Random();
                        int randomImageId = spriteID[generator.nextInt(spriteID.length)];
                        trafficsprites.add(createSprite(randomImageId));
                        try
                        {
                            Thread.sleep(3000); //Waits for 1 second
                        }
                        catch(InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                }
            }).start();

       }

       public void mediumspeed(){

           final int[] spriteID = { 
                   R.drawable.amb,
                   R.drawable.audi,
                   R.drawable.car,
                   R.drawable.mini,
                   R.drawable.truck,
                   R.drawable.taxi,
                   R.drawable.van
                   // etc for as many images you have
           };
           new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                        if (i==5){
                            fastspeed();
                        }
                    Random generator = new Random();
                    int randomImageId = spriteID[generator.nextInt(spriteID.length)];
                    trafficsprites.add(createSprite(randomImageId));
                    try
                        {
                        Thread.sleep(1850); //Waits for 1 second
                        }
                    catch(InterruptedException e)
                        {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                }
            }).start();


       }



      public void fastspeed(){

           final int[] spriteID = { 
                   R.drawable.amb,
                   R.drawable.audi,
                   R.drawable.car,
                   R.drawable.mini,
                   R.drawable.truck,
                   R.drawable.taxi,
                   R.drawable.van
                   // etc for as many images you have
           };
           new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    Random generator = new Random();
                    int randomImageId = spriteID[generator.nextInt(spriteID.length)];
                    trafficsprites.add(createSprite(randomImageId));
                    try
                        {
                        Thread.sleep(1200); //Waits for 1 second
                        }
                    catch(InterruptedException e)
                        {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                }
            }).start();


       }




       private TrafficSprite createSprite(int resouce) {
           Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resouce);
           return new TrafficSprite(this,bmp);
     }





        @Override
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
                 canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
                 policesprite.onDraw(canvas);
    }

       protected void createTraffic(Canvas canvas){
           for (TrafficSprite trafficsprite : trafficsprites) {
               trafficsprite.drawTraffic(canvas);
        }

       }
       protected void createTraffic1(Canvas canvas){
           trafficsprites.get(1).drawTraffic(canvas);

       }

       public static MediaPlayer getCrashSound(){
           return crashsound;
       }
```

When sprites collide i want it to open a new activity, the master sprite is at the bottom of the screen and has its own class Sprite.java, every other sprite is controlled by TrafficSprite.java

Comment: Check if this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745806/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-android-content-contextwrapper-getpackagename

Comment: PlayScreen extends from? an activity? I think the problem is with the context.

Comment: PlayScreen extends from an activity, is that a problem? thanks

Comment: okay. that's not a problem.

Comment: thanks Ishamael, I will read that now.

Comment: And `Crash` class extends from?

Comment: Activity, just added that

Comment: you can't have both TrafficSprite extending Activity and having a custom constructor for it. You can't instanciate activities yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public void CrashScreen(){
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, Crash.class);
      startActivity(intent);

}
```

and in the new Activity set a TextView with the text to show.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the conext from your current activity, usually the MainActivity:

```
public void CrashScreen(){
      Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Crash.class);
      startActivity(intent);

}
```

Take into account you are using an explicit intent, therefore you need the exact class to be run, and it is resolved using a context as the [documentation says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to the stack trace, your error happens [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#ContextWrapper.getPackageName%28%29). The problem is `mBase` is `null`, this means your context is not initialized. This can happen due to various reasons.
Please check the followings:

is this activty listed in the manifest?
is the activty's `onCreate` method finished properly?
is this method called after `onCreate`?

I am sure one of the above is the problem.

**EDIT**
To solve your problem:

in the `PlayScreen` Activity:

```
new TrafficSprite(this,.....) //refers to the activty
```

in `TrafficSprite`:

```
 private Context cntx;
 public TrafficSprite(Context context,GameView gameView, Bitmap bmp) 
{
    cntx=context;
    ....

 public void CrashScreen(){
        System.out.println("hi");
          Intent intent = new Intent(cntx, Crash.class);
          startActivity(intent);

    }
```

By doing this, you will have a valid context.

The problem with your solution was, although you created a class(`TrafficSprite`) which is an `Activity`, but it's context creating methods does not called at all(e.g. `onCreate` does not called).

**Edit2:**

There is a already [getContext()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()) method in SurfaceView class, so that can be used.

```
  public void CrashScreen(){
        System.out.println("hi");
          Intent intent = new Intent(gameView.getContext(), Crash.class);
          startActivity(intent);

    }
```

As your SurfaceView has the activty's context, thats should be good here too.

Comment: thanks! if i set the activity Crash to run from the main menu, it works fine.

Comment: I am trying to launch it from PlayScreen, this activity has already been launched from the main menu via a button

Comment: public void startPlay(View view) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlayScreen.class);
     intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     backgroundmusic.stop();
     startActivity(intent);
     finish();
 }

Comment: TrafficSprite is a gameloop for the cars that i have coming down from the top, it updates their cordinates with the update() method.                                    protected void createTraffic(Canvas canvas){
        for (TrafficSprite trafficsprite : trafficsprites) {
               trafficsprite.drawTraffic(canvas);
        }

Comment: the onDraw runs that class

Comment: This can be done this way, the trafficsprite objects do not have context.

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: i have clearly designed this i a bad way. PlayScreen has a view on top of it called "GameView" this is where th sprites are created, so still no context by doing that, ill add the gameview to my question..