# How to handle a constructor initialized with null?

Tags: java, constructor, java-8

Let there be a class `A`. Class `B` is as follows:

```
public class B {

    private int anInt;
    private String aString;
    ...

    public B(A initObj) {
       anInt = initObj.getIntField();
       aString = initObj.getStringField();
       ...
    }

    ...
}
```

If initObj is `null`, then what makes the most sense is for the `B` object to be null also. But, [according to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103444/can-constructor-return-a-null-object), a Java constructor cannot return a null.

Obviously, it is best to check on the side of the code that is calling the constructor for `B` so as not to call the constructor with a null argument. But, assuming that this possibility occurs, what is the best way to gracefully handle this situation.

**What is the best way to handle a situation where `B` is initialized with `null`?**

Comment: you can include a check inside the constructor for B like --> `if(initObj!=null){//your initialization code}` so that you know that argument with null is taken care of

Comment: @mettleap So that was my first thought, but then I realized i had this dummy object with no data in it at all masquerading as a real object, just waiting to break something downstream. I realized I'd rather just throw an exception at that point.

Comment: maybe a factory pattern? something like B.getNewInstance(initObj); which will return either null if initObj is null or an instantiated B if initObj is valid?

Comment: throw an `Exception`, the faster the better. guava "invented" these `Preconditions` in java I think, and jdk uses it via `Object::requireNonNull` and the like

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options depending on what you want to happen in your application. 
You could change the signature of B constructor to take the int and String parameters instead of A. This way the caller has to deal with a possibly null initObj and B does not have to deal with potentially null arguments in the constructor.
The constructor could also perform a null check on initObj and either don't initialize the fields of B if that is a valid state for B, or throw an exception if this is really invalid.